# Installing JDBC driver in YCSB project

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc, ycsb

I want to benchmark PostgreSQL with the YCSB framework. Therefore I am following the [instructions](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Using-the-Database-Libraries#using-the-jdbc-library) of the projects Github site for using the JDBC library.

The given example says you need a JDBC Driver which i downloaded from [this](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) site. The file I used (not sure whether it is the right one) is the `JDBC3 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.3-1103`. Now I am not sure where to place the downloaded jar in order to run the project. So far I tried to place the JAR in the bin folder before executing the command `$ ./bin/ycsb load jdbc -s -P workloads/workloada`. This resulted in the following error.

```
Error in database operation: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ycsb?user=postgres&password=password
```

Obviously placing the driver JAR in the bin folder did not turn out to be the right location or maybe it is simply the wrong JAR. Can somebody tell me where I have to place the driver and whether the downloaded jar is the correct one?

Comment: If you're using maven, just add a dependency to that library. Otherwise, make sure the driver is inside a folder containing all the jars that will be put in the classpath of the execution of the application, maybe lib or something. This is stated here: **Make sure that the *.jar is available on your classpath, in addition to ycsb.jar** (taken and adapted from the link on *instructions* in first sentence).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How do I add a dependency to the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What helped me was the following. Although I am sure there are better ways to do this.

I added the following dependency to the `POM.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.postgres.driver</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresdriver</artifactId>
  <version>9.3</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath> "Path to JAR on filesystem" </systemPath>
</dependency>
```

`groupId` and `artifactId` can be chosen as you want and `version` is optional. The `scope` should be set to `system` and the `systemPath` has to point to the JAR on the filesystem (e.g. `/home/user/driver.jar`)

Answer (score 0):

The Jar just needs to be on the classpath in one way or another. You can just specify the jar path like so:

```
./bin/ycsb load jdbc -s -P workloads/workloada -cp /path/to/jar
```

-cp lets you manually add things to the classpath